# question about parameterization/Tangential vectors

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, parametric, parametrization

the Semicubical parabola which has the function

$y^2=x^3$

can be parameterized as $(t^2, t^3)$ but also as $(t, t^{\frac{3}{2}})$. Now if I wanted to calculate the tangent vector

I would get $(2t, 3t^2)$ for the first and $(1, \frac{3}{2}t^{\frac{1}{2}})$ for the second.

I want to calculate the tangent vector at the origin (0,0), I would get

$(2\cdot0, 3\cdot0)=(0,0)$ for the first

and
$(1,0)$ in case of the second parameterization.

How can they differ? what mistake did I make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because even though the trace of the two parametrizations (the curve they draw) is the same, their velocity is different.

We define the tangent (unit) vector to a curve as
$$ \mathbf{\tau}\ (t) = \frac{\mathbf{r}'(t)}{|\mathbf{r}'(t)|} $$
when the velocity magnitude $|\mathbf{r}'(t)|$ is nonzero. So it is clear that you just need to pick the appropriate parametrization.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. however now I am  confused, because what does it say about the existence of the tangential vector in (0,0)? It would exist for one parameterization and not exist for the other one?

Comment: @Parinn From a physical point of view, it says that the first parametrization corresponds to a particle which starts at $t = 0$, from the origin, with zero velocity while the second one corresponds to a particle starting at $t=0$, from the origin, with a velocity magnitude of 1 (along the $x$ component).

Comment: Thank you! I now understand it better. Do the different parameterizations have any consequences at the "connection points" when doing piecewise parameterizations? (i.e for the tangential vectors there?)

Comment: @Parinn I updated the answer to include the definition of the tangent vector, it should be now clear. To reply to your question, again, different parametrizations will correspond to particles moving along the same curve, but with different velocity, so the only difference at connection points will be the velocity magnitude. This last question is really general, can't do any better.

Comment: thank you. I understand it now :)